# Symlink with @ symbol?

Tags: filenames, symlink

I found that there is a symlink generated by ruby which has a `@` sign at the path:

> default -> /Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247@gemset

The folder `/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247` exists, but what is the `@gemset` part ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@` character in your example is part of the filename. Most modern *nix filesystems support everything with the exception of `\0` and `/` in filenames. There is nothing special about the `@` character.